# Redirect example.com to rails server running on localhost:3000 leaving apache sites intact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, hosts

I am working on a rails app which runs on localhost:3000. I want example.com to point to localhost:3000. I edited the /etc/hosts file but it doesn't take port number so the request goes to apache. I want apache sites to work as they are but redirect example.com to rails server.

Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just specify example.com:3000 when browsing to your site? If not, I'd suggest using [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) so that Apache can continue to respond on port 80 while also running your app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With Phusion Passenger and /etc/hosts file entry it is working exactly the way I wanted. Phusion Passenger with default instructions did not work. I had to add "RailsEnv development" and "RackEnv development" in apache configuration to make it work. Thanks again for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use mod_proxy?

```
ProxyPass /your_rails_app http://your.server.address:3000
ProxyPassReverse /your_rails_app http://your.server.address:3000
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html